# How to configure (or what should be the mimimum) the log to bare mimimum?

Tags: logging

The log is growing crazy. Someone configured it to log everything and it's growing to 3 GB a day. What is the bare minimum logging I should have so that it does not grow as big yet serves the purpose. Any article or direct help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748656.aspx) article on TechNet. Half way down the page, it tells you to go to Central Admin > Monitoring > Reporting > Configure Diagnostic Logging. From here, you can customize what services should log, number of days to log, and even limit the amount of space that the logs can take up.

Comment: Thanks Tim for the fast reply. That article helps. Thanks again.

Comment: also with 2010, the ULS logs can be stored in SQL server and not on the web/application server.

Comment: Note please that the log items might be valid, so instead of band-aid'ing the issue (if there is one) use uls viewer to filter out low level entries and check if something is wrong with farm